# Purely analytical bijective maps from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

It is easy to construct a bijective map from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $[0,1]$, for example:

$$A\subset \mathbb{N} \mapsto f(A)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{2^k}$$

where $a_k = 0$ if $k\notin A$ and $a_k = 1$ if $k\in A$. But this simple function uses the ``logical function" $\textbf{if}$.

I wonder if there could be a function using just non-logical functions and operators, for example:

$$A\subset \mathbb{N} \mapsto g(A)= \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{a_k}\right)^2$$

being $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots \}$ (the sum will be finite if $A$ is finite and infinite otherwise). It is clear that $g(\mathbb{N}) = 1$ and $g(\varnothing) = 0$. In addition, it seems that if $A\subset B$ then $g(A) \le g(B)$ (this suggests that the function is injective). But, can it be shown that this function is also onto?

Comment: "In addition, it seems that if $A\subset B$ then $g(A) \le g(B)$ (this suggests that the function is injective)" --- This sounds an awful lot like you think $A,B \subset \mathbb{N}$ means either $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$.

Comment: Also, note that using $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3,\ldots\}$ lets you write $f(A) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-a_k}$, so I'm not sure what your distinction is between a function that uses logical operators and one that doesn't.

Comment: Btw, for technical reasons, your $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1/a_k)^2$ ought to be written $\sum_{k \in A} (1/k)^2$ or in other words $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(1/k)^2$ for $a_k = 1$ if $k\in A$ and $a_k=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Your map
$$
A\subset \mathbb{N} \mapsto f(A)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{2^k}
$$
is almost (but not precisely) injective.  Because a few numbers have two different binary expansions.

For topological reasons, there is no bijection $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to [0,1]$
that is **continuous** where the two spaces have their usual compact Polish topologies.  Both of your maps are, indeed, continuous.  So neither one is bijective.  Nor is any map with a similarly simple definition.

Comment: What are these "topological reasons"?

Comment: Theorem: Suppose $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff.  If $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous bijection, then it is a homeomorphism.  Of course $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) $ is not connected, and $[0,1]$ is connected, so they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I do not see that, necessarily, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is disconected (for every possible topology), because it is uncountable and, in addition, contains elements of the Baire space $\mathcal{N} = \omega^\omega$ (the set of all infinite sequences of natural numbers with a certain topology). Clearly, $\mathbb{N}$ is disconnected in any reasonable topology, but I do not see that this entails that we can not define a "connected" topology for $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: As I said above, I use $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ "in its usual compact Polish topology".  That is, the product topology; the topology of pointwise convergence.  The maps in the OP are continuous for that topology.  This is enough to show that the maps in the OP are not bijective.